Authorization is getting failed with correct token with jsonwebtoken
I am working on a project where I have created the registration and login routes. The problem is coming with the profile route, specifically, authorization. What I want is that if the user wants to access the profile route, he should be logged in, for which the provided token should be correct. Please have a look at the code -
auth.middleware.js -
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';



export const authuser = async (req,res,next) => {
    try {
        const token = req.cookies.token || req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1];

        if(!token){
            return res.status(401).send({error: "Please login to see the profile"});
        }

        const decoded = jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET);
        req.user = decoded;
        next();
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error

        )
        res.status(401).send({error: 'Unauthorized User'})
    }
}

user.route.js -
import { Router } from "express";
import * as usercontroller from '../controllers/user.controller.js'
import { body } from "express-validator";
import * as authMiddleware from '../middlewares/auth.middleware.js'

const router = Router();


router.post('/register',
    body('email').isEmail().withMessage('Email must be a valid email address.'),
    body('password').isLength({min:6}).withMessage('Password must be atleast 6 characters long.'),
    usercontroller.createUserController);

    router.post('/login',
        body('email').isEmail().withMessage('Email must be a valid email address.'),
        body('password').isLength({min:6}).withMessage('Password must be atleast 6 characters long.'),
        usercontroller.loginUserController);

    router.post('/profile',authMiddleware.authuser ,usercontroller.profileController)
export default router;

user.controller.js -
import userModel from '../models/user.model.js';
import * as userService from '../services/user.service.js'
import { validationResult } from 'express-validator';

export const createUserController = async (req, res) => {
    const errors = validationResult(req);
    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
        return res.status(400).json({ errors: errors.array() });
    }

    try {
        const user = await userService.createUser(req.body);
        const token = await userModel.generateJWT;
        res.status(201).send(user);
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(400).send(error.message)
    }
}


export const loginUserController = async (req, res) => {
    const errors = validationResult(req);
    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
        return res.status(400).json({ errors: errors.array() });
    }

    try {
        const { email, password } = req.body;
        const user = await userModel.findOne({ email }).select('+password');
        if (!user) {
            return res.status(401).json({
                errors: "Invalid credentials"
            })
        }
        const isMatch = await user.isValidPassword(password);

        if (!isMatch) {
            return res.status(401).json({
                errors: "Invalid password"
            })
        }

        const token = user.generateJWT();
        res.status(200).json({user,token,});
        

        
    }
    catch (error) {
        res.status(400).send(error.message)
    }
}

export const profileController = async (req,res) => {
    console.log(req.user);
    req.status(200).json({
        user:req.user
    })
}

When I'm sending a request from postman as headers with key - "authorization" and value - "beared ". The token is of a already registered user. I'm getting -
{
"error": "Unauthorized User"
} in postman and -
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'token')
at authuser (file:///C:/Users/tejas/OneDrive/Desktop/Tejashv/Programs/Project-A6U7X1/backend/middlewares/auth.middleware.js:7:35) in terminal at vs code. Can someone please tell me that what is the reason behind this problem and how can it be solved ?

suggests req.cookies is undefined - have you checked? try req.cookies?.token in the if statement
